# Ubuntu 15.04 suspends ~30 seconds after resume

Tags: suspend, hibernate, resume

I just upgraded yesterday to 15.04 from 14.10 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. My computer suspends and resumes with no trouble, however every time I resume, after about 30 seconds the computer goes back into suspend. If I resume, the same pattern continues.

Suspending from virtual console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) using `sudo pm-suspend` does not cause the same problem, and I can safely switch to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, suspend, then switch back to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> without running into the auto-suspend problem.

However, if I suspend from the graphical screen (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>), and then switch to the virtual console, it will still automatically suspend. This happens even if within the virtual console I force a suspend before the computer automatically does it and resume, and stay within the virtual console. Every time the computer will automatically suspend again within about 30 seconds.

This makes my computer effectively unusable until I restart, after which it works fine (until I suspend from the graphical interface again, at which point I must restart).

Any ideas on what might be wrong? I have a 2013 Razer Blade 14, which has always worked with previous version of Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered turning off suspend? Have you reviewed this? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me. Have you considered reporting it here? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid

Comment: I had not considered hibernation - however the laptop failed resume after pm-hibernate with an error along the lines of "usb 1-13 ... descriptor read error". I had to do a hard-power-off and turn the computer back on. I will look into submitting a bug report at launchpad. The problem now appears to be intermittent - last night I tried to demonstrate it to a friend, but everything functioned appropriately. This continued until this afternoon, when it started having problems again. I can't think of anything that would be different between then and now.

Comment: Regarding descriptor read error: If you do a google search for this you will see threads  going back years. Be that as it may, it may or may not be connected to your current issue. If you receive a similar error again, please [edit] the exact error into your question as it may be helpful. On the off chance that these issues are connected you may wish to pay attention to what if any devices you have attached to the USB ports when this problem occurs and check to see if the problem still exists when you don't connect them. `lsusb` is useful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, except the second time i resume it does work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm seeing the same problem on my Sony Vaio. Once I manage to get logged into the Lubuntu desktop, it stops suspending every 30 seconds. I think this is because xfce4-power-manager is taking over.

However, if I switch to a console, it immediately suspends, and resumes its "suspend after 30 seconds" behavior. I also see the "suspends after 30 seconds" behavior on the default Unity desktop.

I've found I can put an end to this behavior by making /sys/power/state non-writable (chmod 444), and I can get this to persist between boots by adding the chmod command to /etc/rc.local, before the "cgroup" commands.

Now that I have made /sys/power/sleep non-writable, I'm seeing evidence in syslog of what's going on. Every 30 seconds, I see this:

`Apr 28 11:08:48 socrates systemd-sleep[8831]: Failed to open /sys/power/state: Permission denied`

I'm also seeing other writes to syslog every 30 seconds related to whatever is trying to put the system to sleep, starting with:

`Apr 28 11:31:10 socrates NetworkManager[825]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no enabled: yes)`

After the "Permission denied" error, there are a bunch of messages from NetworkManager waking back up, named reloading its configuration, etc.

These writes to syslog only occur when I'm on the virual console, and stop when I switch back to the Lubuntu desktop.

Update: Issues mostly resolved by switching back to Upstart, as detailed here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Still seeing this every 30 seconds in syslog:

`Apr 28 12:45:51 socrates dbus[775]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)`

This is followed by anacron running. This only happens when using the virtual console.

Update: If I make /sys/power/sleep writable, problem resumes, even after switching from systemd to upstart.

Update: Bug reported. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1450013

Update: Problem completely solved by setting "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" in /etc/systemd/logind.conf.

Comment: Interesting.  Seems strange that this behaviour changes between selecting suspend, and a lid close/open.  Any ideas what changes in the signalling between these two?