# Ubuntu 15.04 jumps into standby after login

Tags: login, suspend

I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 15.04 flawlessly. But for some reason, it always jumps straight into standby (suspend) mode directly after login. I have to use the notebook's power button to wake it up, then it's finally logged in and I can use the system. This is annoying. I'm using a Thinkpad T61.

Here's the log immediatly befor it jumps into suspend:

> moon:/var/log$ cat syslog|grep suspend
>
> May 16 19:27:20 moon kernel: [  838.913403] Suspending console(s) (use to_console_suspend to debug)
>
> May 16 19:27:20 moon kernel: [  839.391898] PM: suspend of devices complete after 478.104 msecs
>
> May 16 19:27:20 moon kernel: [  839.392466] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 0.564 msecs
>
> May 16 19:27:20 moon kernel: [  839.408169] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 15.699 msecs
>
> May 16 19:27:20 moon systemd[1]: Unit suspend.target is bound to inactive unit systemd-suspend.service. Stopping, too.

Comment: It happens every time when I boot up freshly and login.

Comment: It also happens when I use the guest account to login. It once happend too while logging out of the guest session.

Comment: I restarted the system today and it didn't suspend after login for the first time. But the problem should be related to systemd, since it is new in Ubuntu 15.04. Anyway I can't find any information for the cause in systemd's configuration files. I don't know which logs I could check furthermore. But I found out, there is a new aspect to the problem: It also suspends automatically using STRG+ALT+F2 to change to terminal. I have to use the power button to resume it, after logged in in the terminal it doesn't suspend. Switching back to X by STRG+ALT+F7 causes the system again to suspend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody found a solution:

> Problem completely solved by setting "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" in /etc/systemd/logind.conf.
>   From here: [Ubuntu 15.04 suspends ~30 seconds after resume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613092/ubuntu-15-04-suspends-30-seconds-after-resume)

Comment: This helped me too (on 18.04).  I had already set `HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore`, but I had to set `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` as well to solve this problem, even though my laptop is always docked.  Seems like it briefly forgets it's docked after login!